# What are alternatives to declaring data structure in functions?

Tags: c#, data-structures, scope

Is there a good existing or upcoming alternative in C# to declaring data structures in methods? It's possible to use anonymous types, but there are difficulties with declaring them. Let's say I have a hypothetical class:

```
class ThingsManager
{
    private void DoThings(IEnumerable<Thing> things)
    {
        var thingLocations = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach(var thing in things)
        {
            // some complicated logic and checks for current thing;
            // if current thing satisfies all conditions:

            var thingName = thing.Name;
            var thingLocation = location; // taken somewhere from upper lines
            thingLocations.Add(thingName, thingLocation);
        }

        // ... later

        foreach(var thingLocation in thingLocations)
        {
            // here I don't know what is the key and what does the value mean.
            // I could use Linq and anonymous types, but sometimes it is clearer 
            // to use foreach if the logic is complicated
        }
    }
}
```

Now, what I'd like to see:

```
class ThingsManager
{
    private void DoThings(IEnumerable<Thing> things)
    {
        struct ThingLocations
        {
            string ThingName {get;set;}
            string Location {get;set;}
        }

        var thingLocations = new List<ThingLocations>();

        foreach(var thing in things)
        {
            // some complicated logic and checks for current thing;
            // if current thing satisfies all conditions:

            var thingName = thing.Name;
            var thingLocation = location; // taken somewhere from upper lines
            thingLocations.Add(new ThingLocation(thingName, thingLocation));
        }

        // ... later

        foreach(var thingLocation in thingLocations)
        {
            // now here I can use thingLocation.ThingName  
            // or thingLocation.Location
        }
    }
}
```

I could also declare the structure in the class, but it doesn't make sense to use it anywhere except in my function. It would be better if my function were the only place where I could use this data structure. I'm looking for a better way to handle such situations, or at least be able to declare anonymous types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anonymous types would help with the naming aspect, but you would have to translate the input into your anonymous type and the type would remain internal to the method scope.

```
// Assumes thingLocation comes from somewhere...
var thingLocations = things
    .Select(t => new { ThingName = t.Name, Location = new ThingLocation(t.Name, thingLocation) } );
```

It is done using the `Select` extension method in order to project to an anonymous type.

You can declare anonymous types without linq, but you will find it annoying trying to add those to lists / dictionaries:

```
var me = new { Name = "Adam", Age = 27 };
```

---

<sub>I'm going on record to say that I wouldn't take this approach, personally I'd either use anonymous types, a `Tuple<string, string>`, or a custom type.</sub>

Failing all of that, and if you don't mind firing up the DLR, you could use an `ExpandoObject`:

```
    class Thing
    {
        public string Name;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var things = new List<Thing>() { new Thing { Name = "Adam" } };
        var thingLocations = new List<dynamic>();

        foreach (var thing in things)
        {
            dynamic location = new ExpandoObject();
            location.Name = thing.Name;
            location.Location = "here";

            thingLocations.Add(location);
        }

        // ... later

        foreach(var thingLocation in thingLocations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(thingLocation.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(thingLocation.Location);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

This allows you to dynamically add properties as you need them by declaring them on the spot. You can then use these later because `ExpandoObject` provides the plumbing to the DLR when the DLR asks for a member by name.

Comment: The projection is not always that simple, if I need to loop through objects internals and selecting its properties depending on some conditions, I use foreach, and in that case I can't simply declare an anonymous type like that.

Comment: @SurikovPavel Then in that case there is no CLR support for that. There is DLR support and a type called `ExpandoObject` that will do what you want.

Comment: OK, as I understand there is no simple way to do what I need. But at least its possible with ExpandoObject.

Comment: @SurikovPavel There are plenty of simple ways: anonymous type, tuple, or custom type. You can make nested custom types private to only the containing type for internal-only use.

Comment: I'm declaring private structures in class, but I thought that local data structure that is used only in function and nowhere else should be encolsed in its scope.

Comment: @SurikovPavel That makes sense, but the alternative isn't much worse - private to class scope is effectively private all over anyway.

Answer (score 0):

C# does indeed support [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), but the real answer is:

No, you can't do that in C#. Just declare the `struct` as private right above your method and forget about it.

Comment: I know that it supports them, but its not easy to declar anonymous types except using Linq, and I do not use Linq in all cases, sometimes foreach makes the logic clearer.

Comment: `var thing = new { Name=thingName, Location=location }; `
That's not LINQ.

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of your question. What do you want to achieve and why? Remember that the code using anonymous types or temporary types is harder to understand -> higher maintenance costs. Why cannot you just make the type explicit.

Comment: He wants a Tuple. Once you get used to it, it's very convenient. C# doesn't have it (it has a Tuple type, but it's nowhere as convenient as Python's tuples, for instance)

Comment: I can make the type explicit and that's what I'm doing in second example. There question is where I need to put it. If I will declare it in the class, nobody else is going to use it. In method I can't. So now I'm looking for a different way.

Comment: @zmbq A tuple is logical, but I think also the name of the properties on that type is important in this case. A tuple is constrained to `Item1`, `Item2`, etc.

Comment: A tuple is perfect for such a local use. Anyway, this discussion is getting quite long, when all OP has to do is declare a private struct outside the method...

Comment: @zmbq That's what I'm doing now, but I don't like it. If it is used only locally why should it be visible to the whole class.

Comment: @SurikovPavel it really doesn't matter if the rest of the class can see it. If the data structure really is irrelevant to the rest of the class, then it may be that the class is doing too many/unrelated things and needs refactoring anyway (violates SRP)

Comment: @MattDavey I do not agree, this maybe a structure that is useful for some local part of your function, that just relates together several data pieces. The purpose of this structure is to carry these data pieces with good names.